# where in clause in entity famework

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have a requirment to write a query with "where in" clause. I am using entity framework 4.

My sql query is:

```
select ITEMNMBR, locncode, qtyonhnd, atyalloc 
from dbo.iv00102 
where ITEMNMBR IN (
                   SELECT  cmptitnm 
                   from dbo.bm00111
                   where itemnmbr == bomItem)
AND LOCNCODE = 'MEMPHIS'
```

Need a query somthing like this:

```
public static Func<DBEntities, string, IQueryable<IV00102>> compiledMemphisQuery =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((DBEntities ctx, string bomNumber) =>
            from items in ctx.IV00102
            where   items.ITEMNMBR in (
                                        from orders in ctx.bm00111
                                        where orders.itemnmbr == bomItem
                                        select orders.cmpitnm)
            and items.locncode == "Memphis"
            select items);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Contains extension method of the query. It should work:

```
public static Func<DBEntities, string, IQueryable<IV00102>> compiledMemphisQuery =
    CompiledQuery.Compile((DBEntities ctx, string bomNumber) =>
        from items in ctx.IV00102
        where   (
                                    from orders in ctx.bm00111
                                    where orders.itemnmbr == bomItem
                                    select orders.cmpitnm)
        and items.locncode == "Memphis"
        select items).Contains(items.ITEMNMBR);
```

Comment: Anyway, it that's your query, I think you could do a join, or create a relationship between both entities and use SelectMany.